# Application doesn't execute Form1_load method when started by Scheduled Task

Tags: c#

I have an App in C# using Windows Forms. My application is working normally, but when I want to start it by OS (Windows 7) using Scheduled Task, it doesn't load Form1_load method. How could I solve this problem?

Here is a body of Form1_load method:

```
 private void   Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            bool fResult = false;
            fResult = registerDeviceNotification();
            g_oGeneratorManager = new CGeneratorManager();
            if (true != fResult)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Register device notification failed");
                MessageBox.Show("Register device notification failed", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            lblStatus.Text = "Running";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            CLog.Err(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pro-tip, don't put the tags inside the question title. Tags are shown as part of the question therefore it's redundant. What OS are you using? Is the program complex? Can we see what is inside the `Form_Load` method?

Comment: no exception is thrown ?

Comment: Is your OS a 64bit version?

Comment: No exception, I have a 64 bit version. The same problem occurs on Xp 32 bit. Actually this method runs but partially. When I use other application to catch Window handle of these app and send a message, it runs normally but not when appliacation is started with Scheduled Task

Comment: "runs but partially." Does it throw an exception? Issue any kind of error? Do you see a GUI when the program runs? Give us a little more information about the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

task scheduler is mean to execute command-like or console app, without ui.

split out the code you intend to be executed under task scheduler, and wrap these codes under (dll)

then you create 2 separate project with ui:
the 1st is your existing winform, but you changed the code to reuse the dll.
2nd project is console app, similar approach as winform, reuse the dll logic.

now use the console app for the task scheduler.

Comment: maybe change Form to MessageWindow?